# Python code for validating chess king movement

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am new to python and practising questions side by side.
I came across a problem on [snakify.org](http://www.snakify.org/en/lessons/if_then_else_conditions/problems/king_move/) and solved using below code.
Can this code be more simplified?

Problem statement:

Chess king moves horizontally, vertically or diagonally to any adjacent cell. Given two different cells of the chessboard, determine whether a king can go from the first cell to the second in one move.
The program receives the input of four numbers from 1 to 8, each specifying the column and row number, first two - for the first cell, and then the last two - for the second cell. The program should output YES if a king can go from the first cell to the second in one move, or NO otherwise.

I tried this solution on various possible sets and works fine but still, wonder if the lines of code could be reduced?

```
x1 = int(input())
y1 = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
y2 = int(input())
def xcell(x1,x2):
    x=0
    if x1 -x2 > 0:
        x = x1 - x2
    elif  x1-x2 < 0:
        x = x2-x1
    else: x
    return x
def ycell(y1,y2):
    y=0
    if y1 -y2 >= 0:
        y = y1 - y2
    elif  y1-y2 < 0:
        y = y2-y1
    else: y
    return y
if ((xcell(x1,x2) == 1) & (ycell(y1,y2) == 0))or ((xcell(x1,x2) == 0) 
    (ycell(y1,y2) == 1))or((xcell(x1,x2) == 1) & (ycell(y1,y2) == 1)):
     print("YES")
else: print("NO")
```

The expected output is **YES** if the user provides input **4,4,5,4**

Comment: This question is probably better suited for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: You can reduce the problem to computing the distance between the two points. For a move by the king, the distance between the two points must be sqrt(2) = sqrt(1+ 1). On a chessboard the only way to get this distance would be by moving 1 cell away in any direction.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `abs` (absolute value) function to check the movement condition:

```
x1 = int(input())
y1 = int(input())
x2 = int(input())
y2 = int(input())

valid_move = abs(x1 - x2) <= 1 and abs(y1 - y2) <= 1 and (x1, y1) != (x2, y2)
print("YES" if valid_move else "NO")
```

Answer (score 0):

I am starting learning , I see it like this :
`

```
x1=int(input("Введите значение x1:   "))
 y1=int(input("Введите значение y1:   "))
 x2=int(input("Введите значение x2:   "))
 y2=int(input("Введите значение y2:   "))

 if x1-1 == x2 or x1+1 == x2 and y1 +1 == y2 or y1-1 == y2:
     print("Yes")
 elif x1+1==y2-1 or x1+1==y2+1 and x1-1==y2-1 or x1-1==y2+1:
     print("Yes")
 else:
     print("No")
```

`

Comment: Hi Aleksei R., welcome to SO. This site is an English language-only site, please update your answer with English text. Technically, the text you have included is not related to the answer so should be deleted anyway, but if you add a description of how your answer solves the OP's issue, it will make it more useful to future users. Thanks.